# ClassCastException when calling constructor for custom Button class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I`m playing with some simple Android app code but there is problem related to all layouts in code.

This is error when I open layout in eclipse

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.android2.calculator3.view.ColorButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to com.android2.calculator3.Calculator
at com.android2.calculator3.view.ColorButton.<init>(ColorButton.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

And this is my code in Colorbutton.java

```
 package com.android2.calculator3.view;

 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.widget.Button;

 import com.android2.calculator3.Calculator;
 import com.android2.calculator3.EventListener;
 import calculator.app.R;

 /**
 * Button with click-animation effect.
 */
class ColorButton extends Button {
int CLICK_FEEDBACK_COLOR;
static final int CLICK_FEEDBACK_INTERVAL = 10;
static final int CLICK_FEEDBACK_DURATION = 350;

float mTextX;
float mTextY;
long mAnimStart;
EventListener mListener;
Paint mFeedbackPaint;
Paint mHintPaint = new Paint();
Rect bounds = new Rect();
float mTextSize = 0f;

public ColorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Calculator calc = (Calculator) context;
    init(calc);
    mListener = calc.mListener;
    setOnClickListener(mListener);
    setOnLongClickListener(mListener);
}

private void init(Calculator calc) {
    Resources res = getResources();

    CLICK_FEEDBACK_COLOR = res.getColor(R.color.magic_flame);
    mFeedbackPaint = new Paint();
    mFeedbackPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mFeedbackPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    getPaint().setColor(res.getColor(R.color.button_text));
    mHintPaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.button_hint_text));

    mAnimStart = -1;
}

private void layoutText() {
    Paint paint = getPaint();
    if(mTextSize != 0f) paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    float textWidth = paint.measureText(getText().toString());
    float width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    float textSize = getTextSize();
    if(textWidth > width) {
        paint.setTextSize(textSize * width / textWidth);
        mTextX = getPaddingLeft();
        mTextSize = textSize;
    }
    else {
        mTextX = (getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
    }
    mTextY = (getHeight() - paint.ascent() - paint.descent()) / 2;
    if(mHintPaint != null) mHintPaint.setTextSize(paint.getTextSize() * 0.8f);
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
    layoutText();
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if(changed) layoutText();
}

private void drawMagicFlame(int duration, Canvas canvas) {
    int alpha = 255 - 255 * duration / CLICK_FEEDBACK_DURATION;
    int color = CLICK_FEEDBACK_COLOR | (alpha << 24);

    mFeedbackPaint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRect(1, 1, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, mFeedbackPaint);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(mAnimStart != -1) {
        int animDuration = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - mAnimStart);

        if(animDuration >= CLICK_FEEDBACK_DURATION) {
            mAnimStart = -1;
        }
        else {
            drawMagicFlame(animDuration, canvas);
            postInvalidateDelayed(CLICK_FEEDBACK_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
    else if(isPressed()) {
        drawMagicFlame(0, canvas);
    }

    CharSequence hint = getHint();
    if(hint != null) {
        String[] exponents = hint.toString().split(Pattern.quote("^"));
        int offsetX = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_hint_offset_x);
        int offsetY = (int) ((mTextY + getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_hint_offset_y) - getTextHeight(mHintPaint,
                hint.toString())) / 2)
                - getPaddingTop();

        float textWidth = mHintPaint.measureText(hint.toString());
        float width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight() - mTextX - offsetX;
        float textSize = mHintPaint.getTextSize();
        if(textWidth > width) {
            mHintPaint.setTextSize(textSize * width / textWidth);
        }

        for(String str : exponents) {
            if(str == exponents[0]) {
                canvas.drawText(str, 0, str.length(), mTextX + offsetX, mTextY - offsetY, mHintPaint);
                offsetY += getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_hint_exponent_jump);
                offsetX += mHintPaint.measureText(str);
            }
            else {
                canvas.drawText(str, 0, str.length(), mTextX + offsetX, mTextY - offsetY, mHintPaint);
                offsetY += getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_hint_exponent_jump);
                offsetX += mHintPaint.measureText(str);
            }
        }
    }

    CharSequence text = getText();
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, text.length(), mTextX, mTextY, getPaint());
}

private int getTextHeight(Paint paint, String text) {
    mHintPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int height = bounds.height();
    String[] exponents = text.split(Pattern.quote("^"));
    for(int i = 1; i < exponents.length; i++) {
        height += getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_hint_exponent_jump);
    }
    return height;
}

public void animateClickFeedback() {
    mAnimStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(isPressed()) {
            animateClickFeedback();
        }
        else {
            invalidate();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        mAnimStart = -1;
        invalidate();
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

I can not figure out whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log does most of the work for you:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to com.android2.calculator3.Calculator
at com.android2.calculator3.view.ColorButton.<init>(ColorButton.java:39)
```

Essentially, you are attempting to cast `BridgeContext` to `Calculator`, which I assume refers to this line in your constructor:

```
public ColorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Calculator calc = (Calculator) context; //This Line
    init(calc);
    mListener = calc.mListener;
    setOnClickListener(mListener);
    setOnLongClickListener(mListener);
}
```

For this to work, your `context` argument needs to inherit from `Calculator`. A simple test would be:

```
if (context instanceof Calculator) {
    Calculator calc = (Calculator) context;
} else {
    Log.e("Log Tag", context.toString() + " must inherit from Calculator class");
}
```

or, with a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    Calculator calc = (Calculator) context;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e("Log Tag", context.toString() + " must inherit from Calculator class");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit:**

A possible fix for your situation could be the following amendments to your constructor:

```
public ColorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Caculator calculator) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Calculator calc = calculator;
    init(calc);
    mListener = calc.mListener;
    setOnClickListener(mListener);
    setOnLongClickListener(mListener);
}
```

Of course, this is because I know nothing of your custom `Calculator` class (i.e., whether it is even a sublcass of `Context`). This method will bypass the `context` casting completely, so you can pass whatever you like for your first argument for as long as it inherits from the `Context` class (most commonly an `Activity`).

Comment: Yes, this is it. Any suggestion how to fix this code to work? Calculator calc = (Calculator) context;

Comment: @Anna6541 Well, you just need to make sure that wherever you call the constructor for your `ColorButton` class, you ensure that whatever you pass as its first argument is of type `Calculator` :)

Comment: Thanks I will try, I`m newbie in programming :)

Comment: @Anna6541 No problem. FWIW, I've added something to my answer that may help you too. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted as well if it resolved your issue.

Comment: thank you so much for you effort but sadly your code crash my app on startup :( Here is Calculator.java class if this might help anyhow? http://pastebin.com/qy12RcCy

Comment: @Anna6541 Afraid not. However, as your `Calculator` class extends `Activity` (which in turn is a subclass of `Context`), you don't need to bother with my edit and can safely pass `Calculator` as your  `Context` argument. I only added it as I wasn't sure whether or not `Calculator` was a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) Class or not

Comment: I use if (!isInEditMode()) and now works fine. Thank you!